# No swap space after installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: partitioning, mount, swap, fstab

/etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=778f64ee-2798-4207-af19-3aab682d29ec /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

blkid output:

```
B490:~$ sudo blkid 
/dev/sda1: UUID="778f64ee-2798-4207-af19-3aab682d29ec" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="e91b4e1d-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="I0wfRt-pO1S-uxdR-URMd-42ol-NG0F-Nz8qUI" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="e91b4e1d-05"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="2bef7c39-c39d-4367-af0d-ce11f3a0da51" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="8d4582b9-1a67-403d-8c72-d0fd6023aa74" TYPE="swap"
```

[image]

I'm new to Ububtu and not sure whether the partition is correct or not... please help...

Thank you

Comment: Does your Ubuntu install work?

Comment: What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve? What's the output of `swapon -s`?

Comment: swapon -s  <output>$ swapon -s
Filename    Type  Size Used Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition 1863676 226024 -1
not sure why the same is not being show up in /etc/fstab output

Answer (score 1):

Execute the *swapon* command. I have a swap file and this is what I get:

```
$ swapon
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file  10G   0B   -1
```

For another system with swap partition:

```
$ swapon
NAME      TYPE       SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda3 partition  3.9G   0B   -1
```

Note, you do not need to be root or use sudo

Comment: Swapon shows the below:$ swapon
NAME      TYPE      SIZE   USED PRIO
/dev/dm-1 partition 1.8G 221.4M   -1

Answer (score 0):

Try: `swapon /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1`

Answer (score 0):

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204413/dev-mapper-in-fdisk#204438, you have logical volumes or possibly encrypted disks. Read the referenced link. However, it appears to look fine. If you don't want it that way, create a swap partition in the unallocated space or create a swapfile (for file swapping) and use swapon/swapoff to change the swap location and edit your fstab to make that permanent.